# Google Apps Script: Force a library to run with its owner as the user

Tags: google-apps-script

I’ve written a script library in GAS to manage some spreadsheets in my Google Drive.  I’ve attached a couple of functions from the library to a spreadsheet menu, which I’ve shared with some of my colleagues.  I was hoping that would allow them to update some parts of the spreadsheets on my drive.  Unfortunately, the library relies pretty heavily on getting the files by their path in my DocsList.  Consequently, the library and the spreadsheet menu calls to the library work fine for me, but fail when one of my colleagues use the menu.   I’m sure I could work around it by getting everything I need by Id and making sure I share the appropriate files with everyone.  However, I’d like to avoid doing that if at all possible.  Is there was a way to make sure a library always runs as its author?  Such a feature would save me some work, and allow me to write very narrow, focused functions, for use by people whom I do not trust to share all the contents of my directory with.

Comment: No. If you get the root folder by ID, instead of by location in your Drive, you could allow specific function calls that do things to those shared files.

Comment: Right.  But to do that the users would have to have access to my root folder, wouldn't they?  I'd like to avoid that one if I can.

Comment: Yes, they would still have access.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try going into the the script and selecting "Publish" from the top menu and deploy it as a web app? If you do that, you can execute the app as the owner or the user accessing the app. You can also set the access to only you, users in your domain or anyone.

Comment: Ok. But my goal is to be able to get access to the program's functions from the scripts attached to certain other spreadsheets.  I don't see how that will work if all that I have access to is a doGet() function.

Comment: Try making the scripts from the other spreadsheets into libraries too and then call the spreadsheet(s) from the script(s) via the SpreadsheetApp.openById(); function. You can then operate on the spreadsheets from the libraries. Or just put everything into one script and call the spreadsheets from that. I guess it depends on what you are trying to accomplish...